# Ising model autocorrelation of magnetisation per state

Tags: computational-physics, ising-model

I am trying to simulate Ising model, and have learnt that we get more accurate results when we take correlation time $\tau$ into account. I.e, decrease the correlations between observing samples only at intervals after time $2\tau$. and $\tau$ can be found using this equation. $\chi(t) = e^{-t/\tau}$. That is taking log on both sides gives us $.. = -t/\tau$

My question here is won't the correlations $\chi(t)$ be varying from 1 to -1? meaning we can't actually take logarithm and fit a linear curve. I tried to do the same and faced the same problem. I'm including the graph to show it

[image: magnetisation autocorrelations]

we can clearly see there are few values which are below 0. what is the way to find $\tau$ then?
one thing I can do is just draw and fit till autocorrelation hits a negative value. or is there any other way?

[image: limited MC steps so correlation doesn't go negative]

but this takes O(n) extra computation time. I heard we can do FFT of magnetisation say $m(w)$ and IFFT  $m(w)^2$ to get $\tau$.

Does anyone have any code for that FFT method? because I tried to simulate that and got very bad result compared to the actual $tau$(found to be 1270) using the formula given. In the picture below C(t) is the correlation (I called it $\chi(t)$ earlier) $X$ is the observable, $N$ is number of points(mc steps) I have, and obviously t is here representing mc steps
[image: formula for correlation]

where as doing the fft and ifft thing gave me $\tau= 10^5$

this is the code snippet using fft and ifft method of this formula $\tau = \frac{\widetilde\chi(0)}{\tilde(0)}$ where $\widetilde\chi(0)$ is the first term of the ifft of fft of $m(t)-<m>$

```
fm=np.fft.rfft(M1_abs-np.mean(M1_abs)) #fourier of magnetisation - mean mag
fm2=np.abs(fm)**2 
ifm=np.fft.irfft(fm2, len(M1_abs)) 
chi_0= np.mean(M1_abs**2)- np.mean(M1_abs)**2
corr_time = int(ifm[0]/chi_0)
```

Comment: Is $\chi$ what you later call $C$? Please define all your quantities. You should also mention that your data are from MC simulations and that your 'time' is presumably the number of MC steps.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to include the part where the correlation is just noise. Your options are to restrict the fit to a manually chosen range. Taking the range to be from the start to the first negative point should work OK but you will still fit to a bit of noise. Also note that  $\mathcal O(n)$ is not that bad: you are only testing if a number is negative and you can break out of the loop once you found a negative number.

Comment: Is this a 1-D Ising model? You never actually explain your setup in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a normal Monte Carlo algorithm, your measurements should not have a negative correlation, and it is probably due to noisy data. If you want to fit a linear curve I would recommmend to either run more simulations, in order to reduce noise, or you can restrict your data to the domain where the auto correlation is large enough to not be ruined by the noise. Either way you, it is clear that measurements become uncorrelated with a large number of steps.